# Meaning of ある in this sentence

Tags: verbs

王子さまは、王さまに別れの挨拶をして、旅に出ました。夕方、ある町をとおりにかかると、鐘が鳴っています。

What does ある町 mean? I don't see it, is it something like "The town he's in?"

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9951/why-is-it-usually-wrong-to-say-%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-but-ok-to-say-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E4%BA%BA/9954#9954  and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24181/need-help-translating-a-sentence-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B2/24183#24183

Comment: It was no 有る, it was 或る which I just read from a comment. Totally would've never guessed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that context ある means "one" or "some".
ある町 means "some town".

Comment: To add to the answer, I want to point out that it is 或{ある}, not the normal 有る{ある}, so they're separate words that sound the same (and both are normally written in hiragana, which doesn't help).

Answer (score 2):

In this context it means he was passing another town. So 'another' or 'some' may be an apt translation here.